# Show that there are two total orderings of $\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ under which it is an ordered field.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, solution-verification, ordered-fields

Let $\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ be the set of all real numbers of the form $r + s\sqrt{2}$, with $r,s\in\textbf{Q}$. Show that $\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\textbf{R}$. Show that there are two total orderings of $\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ under which it is an ordered field.

**MY ATTEMPT**

In order to prove it is a subfield of $\textbf{R}$, it suffices to define:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
(a + b\sqrt{2}) + (c + d\sqrt{2}) = (a + b) + (c+d)\sqrt{2}\\\\
(a + b\sqrt{2})\times(c + d\sqrt{2}) = (ac + 2bd) + (ad + bc)\sqrt{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and check its corresponding properties. I am mainly interested in the second part, but I do not know how to approach it.

Could someone help me to describe such total orderings?

Comment: Hint: There are two real numbers with the property that their square is equal to $2$. The symbol $\sqrt{2}$ represents a choice of one of them.

Comment: It has two real embeddings and so each induces an ordering restricted from that of the reals.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin could you please provide a full answer? I am totally new to this.

Comment: It is unclear if you are expected to show there are *at least* two orderings, or that there are *exactly* two orderings, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the two maps $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\to\mathbb{R}$, one given by sending the element $a+b\sqrt{2}$ to that real number, and the second to $a-b\sqrt{2}$. Verify that each of them is a field embedding. The usual order of the reals then induces an ordering on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ by transport of structure along each of the two maps, giving you two orderings.

Comment: Thanks again to my stalker for just dropping by and downvoting. It’s that kind of personal grievance that helps the site.

Comment: We've all be there, unfortunately. We just have to learn to live with silly downvoting. And move on. The site lives on.